# LO Calc Basic - What is the right property name for the axis major/minor settings and how to set them correctly?

Tags: charts, basic, libreoffice-basic

Using a libreoffice basic macro for charts, we can control the maximum value of an axis and turn the automatic mode on/off:

```
oAxis.AutoMax = False 
oAxis.Max     = 12345
```

But what are the right property names for

```
Major Interval
Major Auto
Major Time
```

which you can set manually

[image: available settings]

???

Comment: [**StepMain**](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/chart/ChartAxis.html#StepMain) and further down the list?

Comment: Thx! ```StepMain, StepHelp and StepHelpCount``` are known as properties but I cannot set values to them? Currently I'm using LO version 6.4.2.2. Any thoughts?

Comment: The same is true for the boolean properties ```AutoStepMain and AutoStepHelp```. Not possible to change their values. But the macro is running fine. As said, ```Max and AutoMax``` properties and some others are working.

Comment: I haven't looked into your question specifically, but if setting properties has no effect, you may need to replace the entire object that includes those values. That is, instead of `oAxis.StepMain = 1`, do something like this pseudocode: `oAxisNew = CreateUnoObject("com.sun.star.chart.ChartAxis"); oAxisNew.StepMain = 1; oAxisNew.AutoMax = oAxis.AutoMax; oChart.XAxis = oAxisNew`.

Comment: Thx! Setting a value ```oAxisNew.StepMain = 1``` leads to the error: Object variable not set. Any ideas?

Comment: I was wrong with not being able to change the values of the properties. I can change them all. BUT they have no effect what I controlled by open the axis dialog. Even more strange, changing the values in the dialog for ```StepMain, StepHelp``` related properties and show them on macro start shows only the correct boolean values but the Step numbers aren't correct. ???

Answer (score 3):

First, I created a chart with *Insert Chart > Line > Points and Lines*.
Modifying the Y axis with code was fairly straightforward.

For both axes, I went into formatting and specified *Positioning > Interval Marks > Minor > Outer* so that the minor ticks are shown.

```vb
oCharts = ThisComponent.getSheets().getByIndex(0).getCharts()
oEmbeddedObject = oCharts.getByIndex(0).getEmbeddedObject()
oDiagram = oEmbeddedObject.getDiagram()
oYAxis = oDiagram.getYAxis()
oYAxis.StepMain = 40.0
oYAxis.StepHelpCount = 3
```

Here is what the Y Axis properties looked like after running the code:

[image: Y axis properties]

`AutoStepMain` (and the corresponding Major interval checkbox) started out as True, but setting the `StepMain` value via macro changed it to False.

With the X axis, things were more complex. For the scale, there was a choice of Type, and selecting Date seemed to be the only way to control step settings.

After that, instead of `StepMain` (which didn't seem to be relevant in this case), there is a complex structure called `ExplicitTimeIncrement` that specifies the type of increment (Days or Months) along with each value. I didn't dig too far into it, but it looks like it has all of the values you were asking about.

**EDIT**:

I tried the following code, but none of the values were changed, and the last line throws an error stating that the property is read-only (as also shown by MRI). So perhaps the values cannot be modified via the API.

```vb
sTimeIntervalMajor = CreateUnoStruct("com.sun.star.chart.TimeInterval")
sTimeIntervalMajor.Number = 4
sTimeIntervalMajor.TimeUnit = 0
sTimeIntervalMinor = CreateUnoStruct("com.sun.star.chart.TimeInterval")
sTimeIntervalMinor.Number = 1
sTimeIntervalMinor.TimeUnit = 0
sTimeIncrement = CreateUnoStruct("com.sun.star.chart.TimeIncrement")
sTimeIncrement.MajorTimeInterval = sTimeIntervalMajor
sTimeIncrement.MinorTimeInterval = sTimeIntervalMinor
sTimeIncrement.TimeResolution = 1

oXAxis = oDiagram.getXAxis()
oXAxis.ExplicitTimeIncrement.MajorTimeInterval = sTimeIntervalMajor
oXAxis.setPropertyValue("ExplicitTimeIncrement", sTimeIncrement)
oXAxis.ExplicitTimeIncrement = sTimeIncrement
```

It might also be worth posting at ask.libreoffice.org or forum.openoffice.org to see if anyone there can find a way to modify the values, with a link to this question.

Of course, the UNO API isn't the only possibility. You could write a script to unzip the .ods file and modify the XML code with a parsing library such as [xml.etree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) or regular expressions.

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer. I used exactly the same code as in your answer. Due to my limited understanding with basic coding, can you give me a hint please, what is the normal way to handle a structur (access). Thx.

Comment: See edited answer, which shows how to use structures even though it doesn't give a working solution for the X axis.

Comment: Thx a lot Jim K for your help! I asked  the forum of AOO. https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=109001

Comment: What type of chart are you using? In your question to the AOO Forum you say it is a line chart. These don't have an x-axis, they have a category axis like in a bar chart. Only X-Y (Scatter) charts have an actual x-axis. The procedure given in @JimK's answer for setting the properties of the y-axis works for me when applied to the x-axis of an X-Y (Scatter) chart.